# Django rest swagger post parameter not getting displayed on Swagger docs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger-2.0, django-swagger

I have integrated swagger with django rest framework, but the swagger docs does not create a input box to post data for post request.

My settings for parser,

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
    'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
),
```

}

Here is my view class snippet,`

```
class TeamViewList(APIView, BaseView):
"""
    Class based view to handle all operations related to Team Model
"""
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def get_serializer(self):
    return serializers.TeamSerializer

def post(self, request):
    """
    To create a new  team
    """
    try:
```

urlmapping:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^role/$', rest_views.UserTeamRoleView.as_view(), name='user_team_role'),
url(r'^teams/$', rest_views.TeamViewList.as_view(), name='team_list'),
url(r'^teams/(?P<name>[_a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$', rest_views.TeamViewDetail.as_view(), name='team_detail'),
```

]

And my swagger doc generates,
[image]

There is no way to pass the json payload as input to post request.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger doesn't support APIView, you can inherit your view from GenericAPIView

```
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView

class TeamViewList(GenericAPIView, BaseView):
```

Answer (score -1):

You must choose a `PARSER` for your view or add `DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES` to your DRF settings to see form or json object on Swagger.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'rest_framework.filters.SearchFilter',
        'rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'helpers.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_MODEL_SERIALIZER_CLASS': (
        'rest_framework.serializers.ModelSerializer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
    ),
}
```

Comment: I already have that in my settings file, REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
    ),
}

Comment: I have figured out that django-rest-swagger only works for viewset and not for APIView. Is that correct?

Comment: Can you try with ModelViewSet?

Comment: Inherit from GenericViewSet as opposed to ViewSet.

Answer (score -1):

The following method should return an instance not a class:

`def get_serializer(self):
    return serializers.TeamSerializer`

BTW, it was failing for me on DRF `3.6.2` even using an instance instead of a class. However, it looks like [has been fixed here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/schemas.py#L593)

Comment: That's not an issue. swagger docs understand get_serializer method only if the view class extends ViewSet or GenericViewset. But in my case  i am using APIView. There is no support for APIview from swagger.

Comment: I don't think so. I'm using `APIView` and it's calling to `get_serializer()` method

Comment: Could you please post a working example with APIView. That would be helpful for many

Comment: You can use `return serializers.TeamSerializer()` and make sure your `TeamSealizer` class is working

Comment: But after changing ```def get_serializer(self):
    return serializers.TeamSerializer()
```
showing  ```{
  "detail": "Could not satisfy the request Accept header."
}```